Complexity of counting perfect matchings in 3-uniform Hypergraphs (X3C)
I am aware that counting perfect matchings in graphs is #P-complete. I want to know what the complexity is in 3-uniform hypergraphs, i.e., X3C (and more generally in hypergraphs). You could also interpret this as counting the number of exact covers for a set.

It is well known that X3C parsimoniously reduce to 3SAT, so the counting problem is #P-complete
